# Error al importar una clase de un paquete Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

No entiendo tengo creada la clase como pública dentro del paquete `Model`, pero al importarla es como sino existiera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se puede ver el nivel de acceso que tiene tú modelo. Por favor revisa y si este es privado, modifica el acceso a publico o protected.

Comment: Hola Juan especifica que clase y agrega como texto que modificadores tiene la clase